# TypeScript ambient declaration and implementation in separate files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to be able to provide an ambient declaration for an object in one file, but provide the implementation in another

**Example:**

*Test.d.ts*

```
interface TestConstructor {
    new(value?: any): void;
    ...
}

interface Test {
    ...
}

declare var Test: TestConstructor;
```

*Test.ts*

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test(value) {
    }

    return Test;
})();
```

**Error:**

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   'Test' must be of type 'TestConstructor', but here has type '(value:
>   any) => void'.

I know this seems to be an odd way of using TypeScript but the reason is that I want to build an object with features that TypeScript doesn't support (closures / value properties) so I can't use classes for this.

Additionally I want to ship Test.d.ts and Test.js, but NOT Test.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't indicate that `Test.ts` needs to reference `Test.d.ts`, so just compile `Test.ts` by itself

`tsc Test.ts`

instead of

`tsc Test.ts Test.d.ts`

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio in a while, so there may be better ways than these. You could have the files in separate projects. You could also change the Build Action property of Test.d.ts to None, but then if that file contains errors, the compiler won't catch them.